# SQL - request with five table

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

i have five table in a mariadb database, i want to select last value of each name table,

[image]

i do this sql command to have host, name and severity,

i tried this sql command :

```
select host, e.name, e.severity
from hosts
left join items i on (i.hostid = hosts.hostid)
inner join functions f on (f.itemid = i.itemid)
inner join triggers t on (t.triggerid = f.triggerid)
INNER JOIN events e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)
group by hosts.hostid;
```

i want last host, name and severity, i want this result in sql :

[image]

Comment: Which version of MariaDB? 10.2, older, newer?

Comment: i use 10.4.6-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grouping you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify the rows you want. Then filtering is straighforward. For example:

```
select host, name, severity
from (
  select h.host, e.name, e.severity,
    row_number() over(partition by h.host order by e.clock desc) as rn
  from hosts h
  left join items i on i.hostid = h.hostid
  left join functions f on f.itemid = i.itemid
  left join triggers t on t.triggerid = f.triggerid
  left join events e on e.objectid = t.triggerid
) x
where rn = 1
```

Incidentally, if you used a `LEFT JOIN` the subsequent joined tables should also use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: the used method (`Window Function for analytical queries`) is right but expected results do not conform sample data @sdgrhjgh

Comment: is it possible to request a request ?

Comment: @sdgrhjgh Please elaborate. What do you mean by request?